# Share Data between controller actions Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that renders a div that inside of it has links, that updates the look of this div using AJAX.  The issue is Rails has to go and request the same data over and over when switching the view which seem inefficient.

After reading up on the subject of sharing variables between controller actions I understand that this is not possible due to the stateless nature.  Have also read that session should not be used to store object, and these variables contain lots of data, mainly used to generate graphs.   Another option I guess would be Caching which I'm not very familiar with.  Or saving the variables in Javascript on the browser possibly.

Anyone had a similar problem that could provide some guiding?

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        if params[:term]
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html
                format.js {render "show.js.haml"}
            end
        else
            @artists= Artist.all
        end
    end

    def show
        @days=90

        # DATABASE QUERIES
        @artist= Artist.find(params[:id])
        @reach_period= Reachupdate.period(@artist.id,@days)
        @update_period=Update.period(@artist.id,@days)
        @songs_load= Song.by_artist(@artist.id).joins(:playlists)
        @song_period= @songs_load.period(@days)

        # CHART
        @updates= ChartTransformation::pop_chart(@update_period,@days)
        @reach = ChartTransformation::reach_chart(@reach_period,@days)
        @dates= ChartTransformation::dates(@days,3)
        @reach_labels= ChartTransformation::reach_labels(@reach_period,2)
        @songs= ChartTransformation::data_to_releases(@song_period, @days)
        @reach_diff = Reachupdate.diff(@reach_period)
        @pop_diff = Update.diff(@update_period)
        @playlisting= ChartTransformation::playlisting(Playlist.by_artist(@artist.id),@days)

    end

    def overview
        @days=90

        # DATABASE QUERIES
        @artist= Artist.find(params[:id])
        @reach_period= Reachupdate.period(@artist.id,@days)
        @update_period=Update.period(@artist.id,@days)
        @song_period= Song.by_artist(@artist.id).period(@days) 

        # CHART
        @updates= ChartTransformation::pop_chart(@update_period,@days)
        @reach = ChartTransformation::reach_chart(@reach_period,@days)
        @dates= ChartTransformation::dates(@days,3)
        @reach_labels= ChartTransformation::reach_labels(@reach_period,2)
        @songs= ChartTransformation::data_to_releases(@song_period, @days)
        @reach_diff = Reachupdate.diff(@reach_period)
        @pop_diff = Update.diff(@update_period)
        @playlisting= ChartTransformation::playlisting(Playlist.by_artist(@artist.id),@days)


        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render "timeline_content.js.haml"}
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why re-render something which will not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another option I guess would be Caching which I'm not very familiar with

you will have to make yourself familiar with caching. it's the answer to your question.

in your case, it would do a fragment-caching in the view, read the guides https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching